# PWA standalone, dead space after keyboard hide

Tags: javascript, android, html, progressive-web-apps, onsen-ui

I have been trying to find a solution to this for some time without success.

So I have a PWA that has been added to home screen.

User opens the PWA from home screen and goes to a form.

The problem I have is an input at the end of the form.

When you click it to type something in, the keyboard appears over the input.
You scroll down and enter input.

Once you hide the keyboard by tapping somewhere else than the input, a white space stays there where the keyboard was.

[image]

The browser only reclaims the space once user scrolls up even little bit.

I have tried a lot of different ways to trigger the dead space to go away:

- Triggering (using JQuery) different events on blur
- Tried to scroll one pixel up on blur (to simulate scrolling)

I can detect when the space is lost vertically with setInterval but I cannot find a way to inform android to get rid of the dead space.

Comment: I'm seeing this on Android 8.1.0 when moving to and fro between a PWA added to the desktop (so full screen) and a Google Doc that I'm editing. Clicking in the blank space below the PWA footer does nothing. If I go to a PWA page with text input, and click on an input then out, the screen resets. Have you find a programmatic solution - JavaScript or CSS?

Comment: Not a proper solution. I sidestepped my issue by adding margin at bottom of last input (so at the end of the page) so the keyboard first in there and it does not create the funky white space.